# Find duplicated items in a list with limited heap

Tags: java, algorithm

There is an N + 1 length, read-only list of numbers between 1 and N.
There is a duplicate item in the list, but there may be more.
For Example N=3, items of the list [1,3,1,3]
I need an algorithm that prints the duplicated items.(doesn't matter how many times an item is in it)
Based on the example above, the result is 1,3
I need a solution in java that works with limeted heap(can run with many items in short time)

I've tried to create a new HashSet and add items from the list to the set, and if it already contains the item, I've saved it to an ArrayList.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(5);

    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet();
    List<Integer> duplicatedList = new ArrayList<>();   

    for (Integer item : list) {
    if(set.contains(item)) {
        duplicatedList.add(item);
    }
    set.add(item);
}
System.out.println(duplicatedList +" "+ list);
```

It works, but i think this is not too effective. Is there a more efficient solution, for this problem?

Comment: Replace `if(set.contains(item))` with `if (! set.add(item))`, so you don't need to access the `Set` twice per item. Other than that, the code

Comment: The famous interview question limits the duplicated to a single one. In this case there are more efficient algorithms. There also are interesting solutions when you know the number of duplicates in advance. Anyway, what do you mean by "limited heap"?

Comment: Not as efficient as a set, but how about sorting the list in-place?

Comment: By the way, you definitely missed the brace. `set.add(item);` is outside of the loop...

Answer (score 1):

If you want limited heap usage, remove non-duplicates from the original list, instead of creating a new list. Also use [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) to track already seen numbers.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,1,2,5));
int N = list.size() - 1;

BitSet present = new BitSet(N);
for (Iterator<Integer> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    int value = iter.next();
    if (! present.get(value)) {
        present.set(value);
        iter.remove();
    }
}
System.out.println(list);
```

*Output*

```
[1, 2]
```

If original list is read-only, build a new list like in question.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,1,2,5);

BitSet present = new BitSet();
List<Integer> duplicatedList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Integer item : list) {
    if (present.get(item))
        duplicatedList.add(item);
    else
        present.set(item);
}
System.out.println(duplicatedList +" "+ list);
```

*Output*

```
[1, 2] [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5]
```

The main improvement is the use of `BitSet` instead of `Set<Integer>`, relying on the fact that the range of numbers is limited to be between 1 and N, so the space used is lot less (except in extreme conditions).

Comment: Unfortunately the original list is read-only. I can't change it :/

Comment: How does removing the item improve the performance to compare with adding? I'm a C++ adept, could miss something in Java, but from my point of view ArrayList should have adding more efficient than removing.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov This answer is about minimal heap usage, not performance, since I interpreted *space* ("with limited heap") as being the main criteria for "efficient", not *performance*.

Comment: @Andreas If you have a limited heap and a very long list, you may try to iterate the list multiple times. That is not efficient from the time complexity but that is the only solution for limited memory and no limitations on data. BitSet doesn't come for free either.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov True, but `BitSet` is a *lot* cheaper than `Set<Integer>`, and with similar _O(n)_ time complexity, addressing the request for *"a more efficient solution"*, while iterating the list multiple times is _O(n²)_.

Comment: @Andreas My point is: removing duplicates from the ArrayList is a horrible solution. The only (hypothetical) benefit is that removing something we don't require memory (to compare with the solutions where we store something).